# javascript map function returned undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const filteredNumbers = numbers.map((num, index) => {
  if (index < 3) {
    return num;
  }
});

// filteredNumbers is [1, 2, 3, undefined]
```

According to my understanding callback function should return all numbers of array if their index is less than 3 so it should return 1,2,3 and stop after that and number 4 can not be returned as if condition says index should be less than 3.
I am wondering why it returned undefined for index 3 number.

Comment: `map` maps every element. take `filter` instead with a boolean return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.map is an isomorphism and preserves the length of the given array.

So if the callback function does not return anything, the index will be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You want to user a `filter` function instead if you need to filter array elements that meet a certain condition.

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const filteredNumbers = numbers.filter((_, index) => index < 3);

console.log(filteredNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to get the first 3 items in the array, I recommend using slice.

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(numbers.slice(0, 3));
```

Second solution is use filter instead of map.

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const filteredNumbers = numbers.filter((num, index) => {
  return index < 3
});

console.log(filteredNumbers)
```